# How do I complete "Find the Bitizen"?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In tiny Death Star, Palpatine has given me the mission "Find the Bitizen" with the text "Working for tips is acceptable. Find 1 Bitizen(s)."

I assumed I had to wait for one of the events where you have to find a "rebel scum" and tap on it to get rid of. One of those events finally popped up but it did not complete the mission.

How do I complete this mission?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to wait for a mission (similar to "find the rebel spy") where someone is looking for a friend (or one of a number of other "find so-and-so" missions) and then find them. I almost gave up on that mission, but patience finally paid off.

Comment: Thank you, it finally popped up! Now I'm waiting for an upgrade VIP. This game is too addicting.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up paying the 2 bux to skip this mission because I had the same problem as you - had done a few "Find the Rebel Spy" missions with no change.  However, about a minute after I'd skipped it, I got a mission which said something like "So-and-so is looking for his friend! Can you find him?" and when I found them, it said, "Congratualtions, you found the bitizen!"

So from the wording, I'm wondering if maybe that would have completed the mission, if I'd waited a bit longer for it.  So spy missions aren't the same as find someone missions.